# Undefined Error Mp3 Player in Facebook After Sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I m getting "undefined" error in default facebook mp3 player after sharing a link from My Site.

I have checked n rechecked all the og:MEta Tags ..  last nite it was working.. since today morning its not working..

any one can help me out ???

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug from Facebook since some days, I would say at the same time they changed something with the time line. Be patient, all have the same problems and Afaik many also informed FB about this bug.